List all issues of a rule with the NDepend API
I am starting using the NDepend API and still struggling with come basic concepts.
I would like to list all issues associcated with a certain rule.
(I am using X# instead of C# so the syntax is a little different)
First I load the project, run an analysis and get all the issues:
VAR ndprojPath := "Test.ndproj".ToAbsoluteFilePath()
VAR ndProject := ndManager.LoadProject(ndprojPath)
// Do an analysis
VAR analysisResult := ndProject:RunAnalysis()
VAR issuesSet := analysisResult:ComputeIssues()

Now I enumerate all the rules:
FOREACH nRule AS IRule IN issuesSet:AllRules

Now I would like to get the issues of reach rule with the GetIssues() extension method:
VAR nIssues := nRule:GetIssues(???)

My question is: Where do I get the parameter from? It has to be of type IQueryExecutionSuccessResult? I read from the documentation that this type is used with code queries but there is no code query involved?

The solution is to have the rule compiled and executed as a query first:
FOREACH nRule AS IRule IN issuesSet:AllRules
    LOCAL query := ndProject:CodeQueries:CodeQueriesSet:AllQueriesRecursive.FirstOrDefault({;
        q => q.QueryString.Contains(nRule:Name)}) AS IQuery
    LOCAL qCompiled := query:QueryString:Compile(analysisResult.Codebase) AS IQueryCompiled
    LOCAL qResult := qCompiled:QueryCompiledSuccess:Execute() AS IQueryExecutionResult
    VAR nIssues := nRule:GetIssues(qResult:SuccessResult)
    FOREACH nIssue AS IIssue IN issuesSet:AllIssues
        ? i"   >>> Codeelement: {nIssue.CodeElement.FullName}"
        ? i"   >>> Severity: {nIssue.Severity}"
        ? i"   >>> Depth: {nIssue.Depth}"
    NEXT
NEXT

Again, this is X# so the syntay is a little different from C#.

Since you have a IIssuesSet you have access to this method issuesSet.Issues(rule):
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets all issues of <paramref name="rule" />.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="rule">The rule on which to get the issues.</param>
  /// <remarks>This property getter has a constant time complexity.</remarks>
  /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Thrown if this issue set doesn't contain the <paramref name="rule" />.</exception>
  IReadOnlyList<IIssue> Issues(IRule rule);


So there is no need to recompile all the queries.

No all issues are already in the issues set

For the sake of completeness, this is the complete loop that prints out all issues associated with each rule:
VAR ndprojPath := "Test.ndproj".ToAbsoluteFilePath()
VAR ndProject := ndManager.LoadProject(ndprojPath)
VAR analysisResult := ndProject:RunAnalysis()
VAR issuesSet := analysisResult:ComputeIssues()
FOREACH nRule AS IRule IN issuesSet:AllRules
    VAR nIssues := issuesSet:Issues(nRule)
    FOREACH nIssue AS IIssue IN issuesSet:AllIssues
        ? i"   >>> Codeelement: {nIssue.CodeElement.FullName}"
        ? i"   >>> Severity: {nIssue.Severity}"
        ? i"   >>> Debt: {nIssue.Debt}"
    NEXT
NEXT

